# how do I capture the alt= value for link on Adobe DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm new to Adobe DTM so please be gentle with me! What I'm trying to do is track a 'click' but populate the Alt= value of that link into a variable. We do not have a data layer.

Any assistance you could provide would be very welcome

For example:
B.S. widetry Development

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do it is in your event based rule, create a condition as custom data type, and within there, you can use `this` to reference the clicked element. So for example, you can do

```
_satellite.setVar('altText',this.getAttribute('alt'));
return true;
```

This will put the value in a data element so you can reference in the fields with `%altText%` or in code boxes with `_satellite.getVar('altText')`